# Losing my table inside of a subquery... what's the issue?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've got two tables set up, here is a basic example of the setup:

```
 Table1           Table2
 ____________     ____________
|id   |date  |   |id   |stuff |
|_____|______|   |_____|______|
```

so they both have an id column. I'm trying to update table1 in this fashion:

```
update Table1
set [date] = (select [stuff] 
              from Table2 
              where Table2.id = id)
```

However, in the line `where Table2.id = id`, it uses the id field from `Table2` instead of using the one from `Table1`.

When I try `where Table2.id = Table1.id`, I get an error. How can I keep tracking Table1's id per row to use in the subquery for Table2?

Comment: Try usingTable2.id = Table1.id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reference the id inside the inner query to table 1.
This should solve your problem:

```
update Table1
set Table1.[date] = (select Table2.[stuff] 
                     from Table2
                     where Table2.id = Table1.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `Join`:

```
Update t1 set t1.[date] = t2.[stuff]
from Table1 t1 
      join Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

here's the join version,

```
update  a
set     a.[date] = b.[stuff]
FROM    Table1  a
        INNER JOIN Table2 b
           ON a.ID = b.ID
```